# Spanish Language meets Stack Overflow

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Tengo una pregunta sobre el idioma español, que en principio cumple los requisitos establecidos para preguntar en este sitio (es sobre el idioma español, tiene respuesta definida, y algo me la he trabajado), pero que para ser respondida con exactitud es necesario (con un 99,9% de certidumbre) escribir un algoritmo, suponiendo que se cuenta con los datos de entrada adecuados. No sería posible buscar en documentación ya existente como solemos hacer habitualmente.

¿Tendría cabida una pregunta así en este sitio?

Answer (score 5):

Creo que escribir un algoritmo está fuera del ámbito de este sitio, pero eso no hace a tu pregunta off-topic. Aparte, como muchos usuarios han llegado a este stack desde *Stack overflow* posiblemente entre la comunidad **sí** puede haber gente con los conocimientos necesarios para responder.

Quizá lo estás pensando un poco demasiado. Creo que deberías hacer la pregunta. Si luego hay que discutir un poco sobre ella aquí en meta (pero ya viendo la pregunta en sí), se hace tranquilamente.

Si la pregutna fuese "too broad" o tuviese otros problemas, como siempre podemos intentar mejorar la entre todos. Si resulta que es off-topic y hay que cerrarla, tampoco es el fin del mundo.

Yo el mayor problema lo veo en gente de "gatillo fácil" que vota negativo en lugar de hacer comentarios para mejorar un post (o que vota negativo pero nunca retracta el voto una vez el post ha sido editado y mejorado).

Lo que va a pasar es que vamos a explorar nuevas posibilidades para hacer preguntas u otro tipo de preguntas que podemos hacer en el foro, y eso puede traer un valor incalculable a este sitio.  Otras ideas tuyas como el *translation golf* lo demuestran.

Creo que esta comunidad se puede beneficiar de arriesgar e innovar (de hecho estamos explorando si sería bueno el admitir cierto tipo de preguntas tipo lista), y si fracasamos por lo menos nos queda lo aprendido. No nos dejemos desaminar por ver la pregunta cerrada si al final resulta que no puede ser.

En definitiva, yo creo que deberías hacer la pregunta, incluir un link a esta discusión en un comentario, y podemos juzgar un poco más viendo la pregunta en sí.

Comment: Pregunta planteada. Lo que ahora pienso es en si debería añadirle la etiqueta "juego" o incluso si solicitar convertirla en CW, pero entonces la gente no ganaría reputación por sus esfuerzos (de ahí la nota de que voy a poner una recompensa). Sin embargo, me entra la duda: ¿se pueden dar recompensas en preguntas marcadas como CW?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo sí se puede: [How does Community Wiki mode affect bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/209901) _Bounties are not affected by community wiki mode. When you award a bounty to an answer marked community wiki, the reputation bonus will be awarded to the user who posted the original revision of the answer_.  De todos modos, no veo necesario convertirla en CW. Es del tipo [What commercial flight route requires the most (minimum possible) stops/layovers from A to B?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81783/6997) y allí tampoco se optó por CW.